# Java Bridge Pattern Issue

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

I was going through Bridge pattern and got few doubts.I got below code from a site where i created an abstarct class as an interface.

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    protected Workshop workShop1;
    protected Workshop workShop2;

    protected Vehicle(Workshop workShop1, Workshop workShop2) {
        this.workShop1 = workShop1;
        this.workShop2 = workShop2;
    }

    abstract public void manufacture();
}


public interface Workshop {
    abstract public void work();
}
```

**Doubt here is why we have created a constructor declaring 2 objects for the interface?**

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    public Car(Workshop workShop1, Workshop workShop2) {
        super(workShop1, workShop2);
    }


    @Override
    public void manufacture() {
        System.out.print("Car ");
        workShop1.work();
        workShop2.work();

    }

}
```

**Same thing here why again declaring a constructor while passing reference objects of interface?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why we have created a constructor declaring 2 objects for the interface? I am not able to UNDERSTAND THIS THING

Comment: Could you please share tutorial link also

Comment: http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/bridge-design-pattern/ Here it is ..

Comment: I don't see that tutorial as enlightening at all.  They seem to present a trivial case which, in my opinion isn't even a good one in its own right.  The manufacturing process for a bicycle should be quite a bit different than the manufacturing process for a car.  You cannot use just any random `Workshop` object to create your bicycle/car object and thus I don't see what has been decoupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface defines, well exactly that, an interface for common objects.  All objects that implement the interface *must* implement the methods defined in the interface.  So you have a `Car` class which extends your `abstract class Vehicle` and thus *must* implement the the `void manufacture()` method.  In addition though, classes extending `Vehicle` will *also* get the variables defined in the abstract class.  Also, extending classes *must* call one of the constructors defined in the abstract class (if no constructors are defined, then no need to call anything).

The fact that `Vehicle` has a constructor which takes two `Workshop` objects means that when you try and instantiate *any* vehicle (i.e. `Car`), you *must* provide objects which implement the `Workshop` interface.

The missing piece to your puzzle is a concrete class which implements the `Workshop` interface.  As a trivial example if you had:

```
public class NoWork implements Workshop{
    @Override
    public void work(){
        // do no work
    }
}
```

Then you could instantiate your `Car` class by the following (as an example):

```
public static void main(String ...args){
    final Workshop noWork1 = new NoWork();
    final Workshop noWork2 = new NoWork();
    final Vehicle car = new Car(noWork1, noWork2);
}
```

Notice that since `NoWork` implements `Workshop` it is *also* of type `Workshop` thus it's legal to declare `noWork1` (and 2) as `Workshop` objects event though they are actually `NoWork` objects.  Likewise, notice that since `Car` extends `Vehicle` it's find to declare `car` as a `Vehicle` even though it's actually a `Car` (but remember `Car` *is* a `Vehicle`).

Just to clarify though, you *don't* necessarily need to provide two `Workshop` classes to every extending class to `Vehicle`, you could have something like:

```
public class NoVehicle extends Vehicle{
    public NoVehicle(){
        super(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void manufacture(){
        // do nothing...there's nothing to be done
    }
}
```

But notice that *any* extending class *must* call the super constructor.

Comment: Exactly Jared Thanks a lot for explaining. The missing class is already there from where i was going through the tutorial. The point where i was confused was the **requirement of constructor** is it mandatory to have one?? and specifically for this pattern?

Comment: The fact that Vehicle has a constructor which takes two Workshop objects means that when you try and instantiate any vehicle (i.e. Car), you must provide objects which implement the Workshop interface. Here is my answer which you gave thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

If You see the bridge pattern diagram in tutorial [link](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/bridge-design-pattern/), They have assumed that there is two type of workshope

1. Producer
2. Assemble

So thay have used two instacne of workshope Interface one for Producer and one for Assemble.